# making php on-input search but jquery $.ajax and $.post not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to make a live search box using ajax using the following code but its not working. When i `echo "hello";` from the php file and remove everything else it just echos it out on the screen and does not work, no errors or return values, leading me to believe it has to do with my jquery code but i am not sure.

jquery:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
var value = $("#search").val();
$.post(walldb.php, {value: value}, function(data){
console.log(data);
})
});
```

heres the php:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$searchq = "%{$_POST['value']}%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE :s");
$stmt->bindParam(':s',$searchq);
$result=$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $mlink = $row['mainlink'];
  $tlink = $row['thumbnail'];
  $dlink = $row['download'];
  $info = $row['info'];
  $val = $row['wallname'];
  $arr[] = '<li>' . "<a href=" . "$mlink" . " data-lightbox='searchwall'> <img class='searchicon' src=" . "$tlink" . "></a>" . "<span>" . "$val" . "</span><img class='searchbutton1 s1' src='/images/info.png'>" . '<br>' . "<a id='wall1.download' href=" . "$dlink" . "><img class='searchbutton2' src='/images/download.png'></a>" . '<br>' . "<ul class='searchmenu menu1'><p>" . "$info" . "</p>
  </ul>" . '</li>';
}
$final = '<ul>' . implode('', $arr) . '</ul>';
echo $final; //just echos everything on the screen :(
?>
```

html:

```
<form action= "" method= "post">
  <a href="#"><img id="glass" src="/images/search.png" type= "submit" name="submit-search"></a><input id="search" name="search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search By Name" autocomplete="off"><a href="#"><img id="cancle" src="/images/cancle.png"></a>
</form>
```

i would also appreciate some help on making the whole thing work making it search on input since i am very new to pdo/php.

Comment: You have to output the result from your php like `echo($final);`, otherwise your AJAX request will not get anything back.

Comment: i tried, it just echos it onto the screen, as mentioned in the first three lines

Comment: `but its not working` isn't really mentioning it. What is not working? What does your HTTP request in the dev tools show? Any return value? Whats the HTTP code?

Comment: i am sorry for the confusion, no errors, no return values.

Comment: Ohhh....you have the PHP snippet in the same file as the javascript don't you?

Comment: no, different files

Comment: Please do not ass PDO tag. You just confirmed in your question your problem is not PHP related.

Comment: Such a request makes your question a complete off topic.

Comment: i apologize. pdo tag was included because theres pdo in the code snippet and i could have coded it wrong. i removed the tag anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this issue by using generic javascript XMLHttpRequest, jquery never worked for me and i have no idea why. I would love to receive some insight as to why my below solution works and the jquery version does not (i am using the latest version of jquery).

javascript:

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var value = $("#search").val();
  http.open("POST", 'walldb.php', true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.onload = function () {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      $("#result").html(this.responseText);
    }
  }
  http.send("value=" + value);
});
```

php:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$searchq = "%{$_POST['value']}%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE :searchq");
$stmt->bindParam(':searchq',$searchq);
$result=$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $mlink = $row['mainlink'];
  $tlink = $row['thumbnail'];
  $dlink = $row['download'];
  $info = $row['info'];
  $val = $row['wallname'];
  $arr[] = '<li>' . "<a href=" . "$mlink" . " data-lightbox='searchwall'> <img class='searchicon' src=" . "$tlink" . "></a>" . "<span>" . "$val" . "</span><img class='searchbutton1 s1' src='/images/info.png'>" . '<br>' . "<a id='wall1.download' href=" . "$dlink" . "><img class='searchbutton2' src='/images/download.png'></a>" . '<br>' . "<ul class='searchmenu menu1'><p>" . "$info" . "</p>
  </ul>" . '</li>';
}
$final = '<ul>' . implode('', $arr) . '</ul>';
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {  //added this
echo $final;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to correct that:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute([$searchq]);
```

to

```
$searchq = '%' .$_POST['value']. '%'; //edited 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $searchq);
$stmt->execute();
while($row= $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
```

Or PDO

```
$searchq = '%' .$_POST['value']. '%'; //edited 
$stmt= $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE :searchq');
$stmt->bindParam(':searchq', $searchq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
while($row= $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
```

Comment: undefined method bind_param and store_result

Comment: its bindParam() for pdo, still though does not solve my problem

Comment: thanks! however it still just echos everything out on the screen though instead of passing it to jquery

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why does changing these lines change anything related to the **output** of the JSON content?

Comment: @NicoHaase if you saw the 3 edited post you will see why i correct query.

Comment: I cannot see "the 3 edited post" you are refering to, and others should not be required to read other stuff first before they read your answer. Better put everything you need to answer the question in your answer to make it as self-containing as possible

Comment: If you click on "edited 8 hours ago"  in question post you will see all edit from user, and you will see my answer was correct

Comment: I don't question that your answer is "correct" (whatever that means). I've asked you about an **explanation** of your answer. If your code is correct, other users that come along this answer should be able to **learn** from your answer. They should be able to see **why** your code solves the problem, and that's what is still missing from your answer